# .htaccess rewrite rule - Does not work without subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I hope someone can help me out here. I try to set up my .htaccess file to turn this:

```
myurl.com/pages/customers.php?bid=user
```

into this:

```
myurl.com/user/customers
```

I started with this code in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/pages/([^/]+) /pages/$2.php?bid=$1 [NC]
```

That redirect the following url succesfully:

```
myurl.com/user/pages/customers
```

However, I cannot figure out how I can remove the "/pages/" part from the url.

If I try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) /pages/$2.php?bid=$1 [NC]
```

I get an internal server error and I really do not know why.

Any help is greatly appreciated (it also helps to restore my sanity).

Thank you!!

Jan

Comment: where did you get `myurl.com/user/pages/customers` URL?

Comment: In my address bar. If I type that in with the code I have, I get the content of myurl.com/pages/customers.php?bid=user

But I cannot make my code working, that I don't need "/pages/" in the url.